# How can a member view past and present pledges?

Tags: pledges

How do I add a Pledge so that he may view & pay pledges thru the self-service payments page? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please clarify your question. What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

You can give your contacts (who have a user login) access to their Contact Dashboard - and once there they can see Pledges

If you don't have CiviPledge enabled go to Admin > System Settings > Enable components.

If you have enabled it but don't see it you may need to go back to your Permission settings and enable those.

You will also find that when you add a Pledge it offer a SelfService Payments Page option.

Maybe worth reading the [chapter](https://book.civicrm.org/user/current/pledges/setup/) in the civi book